# How to define model property for master detail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a post model that for every post it's need to define category and tag , and from category or tag I wanna to reach all of posts that have that category of tag.
this is my blog model

```
 public class Post
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public string Summary { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public string UrlSlug { get; set; }

        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public Tag Tag { get; set; }
     }
```

and this is Category:

```
public class Category
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string UrlSlug { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

        public IList<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
```

and finally this tag model:

```
public class Tag
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string UrlSlug { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

        public IList<Post> Posts { get; set; } 
    }
```

I just want to know what I've done in designing model is right or not ??

Comment: It looks fine but it all depends on how you want to use this and whether your Posts Lists will be lazy or eager loaded. Those collections could grow very large potentially. So a follow-up question is: What do you plan on using those Posts collections for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need the lists in the model ( remove  public IList Posts { get; set; }

First create two get actions in the controller that takes tag ID, and the other`category ID. Inside the this actions get all the posts and populate your View ( detail view)

```
public ActionResult PostsByCategoryID(Guid Id)
{

  List<post> posts = ///get them by id

 return View(posts) ; //the view take list and displays the posts
}
```